# Installing Bluez in Python3

Tags: bluetooth, python3

How do I install bluetooth/bluez modules into python3? In Python2 I'm able to import bluetooth and utilize it but in Python3 I have no such luck. How can I import bluetooth modules in python3?

Comment: Which python module do you use? PyBluez doesn't seem to support python3 yet (like so many other modules). There is no bluetooth+python3 package in the repo for Ubuntu 12.04. So you have to find a library or try to find a way to use bluetooth "by hand", as PyBluez is also only a wrapper itself.

Comment: I would be happy with any module that works on Linux

Answer (score 2):

pybluez is now ported to python3:
http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth support is native in socket.socket for python 3.3.

Comment: Although this is only one part of what PyBluez provides: you usually need the service discovery APIs before you know who to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

i just tried

```
sudo -H pip3 install pybluez
```

Comment: You indicate that you tried a command, but what was the result?  Does this command provide a solution to the question that was asked?